# How to get all the possible variations of a word with interchangeable letters?

Tags: php, arabic

In Arabic, a letter like "ا" (Alef) has many forms/variations:

(ا, أ, إ, آ)

also it's the same case with the letter ي, it could also be ى.

What I am trying to do is to get ALL the possible variations of a word with many أ and ي letters.

For example the word "أين" should have all these possible (non-correct in most cases) variations: أين, إين, اين, آين, أىن, إين, اىن, آىن ... etc.

Why? I am building a small text correction system that can handle syntax mistakes and replace faulty words with the correct ones.

I have been trying to do this in the most clean way possible, but I ended up with a 8 for/foreach loops just to handle the word "أ"

There must be a better more clean way to do this! Any thoughts?

Here is my code up to this point:

```
        $alefVariations = ['ا', 'إ', 'أ', 'آ'];
        $word = 'أيامنا';

        // Break into letters
        $wordLetters = preg_split('//u', $word, null, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
        $wordAlefLettersIndexes = [];

        // Get the أ letters
        for($letterIndex = 0; $letterIndex < count($wordLetters); $letterIndex++){
            if(in_array($wordLetters[$letterIndex], $alefVariations)){
                $wordAlefLettersIndexes[] = $letterIndex;
            }
        }

        $eachLetterVariations = [];
        foreach($wordAlefLettersIndexes as $alefLettersIndex){
            foreach($alefVariations as $alefVariation){
                $wordCopy = $wordLetters;
                $wordCopy[$alefLettersIndex] = $alefVariation;

                $eachLetterVariations[$alefLettersIndex][] = $wordCopy;
            }
        }

        $variations = [];
        foreach($wordAlefLettersIndexes as $alefLettersIndex){
            $alefWordVariations = $eachLetterVariations[$alefLettersIndex];

            foreach($wordAlefLettersIndexes as $alefLettersIndex_inner){
                if($alefLettersIndex == $alefLettersIndex_inner) continue;

                foreach($alefWordVariations as $alefWordVariation){
                    foreach($alefVariations as $alefVariation){
                        $alefWordVariationCopy = $alefWordVariation;
                        $alefWordVariationCopy[$alefLettersIndex_inner] = $alefVariation;

                        $variations[] = $alefWordVariationCopy;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        $finalList = [];
        foreach($variations as $variation){
            $finalList[] = implode('', $variation);
        }

        return array_unique($finalList);
```

Comment: What your talking about is probably best achieved with machine learning/AI

Comment: @Joseph_J ammm, really?! Could it be that complex? I am hoping that some guru will come and give me like a 10 lines solution or something :)

Comment: Would it work to first reduce input to base characters and then build a result array by stepping through the simplified word with a recursive replacement, to generate all possibilities? The base character could be the replacement-matrix key.

Comment: Well, I think you answered the question yourself, it took you 8 loops for a simple word.  I took your question to be that you were looking for a predictive text application.  Languages are hard to code.  All the worlds best are still trying to perfect it.

Comment: @Teson I don't think this would work, If I understood you well.

Comment: Could you remove the quotes around the letters in your OP as it makes them difficult to read, I'd do it but it seems to mess with the letters themselves.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is the way to do autocorrect, but here's a generic solution for the problem you asked. It uses recursion and it's in javascript (I don't know php).

```js
function solve(word, sameLetters, customIndices = []){
    var splitLetters = word.split('')
                .map((char, index) => { // check if the current letter is within any variation
                    if(customIndices.length == 0 || customIndices.includes(index)){
                        var variations = sameLetters.find(arr => arr.includes(char));
                        if(variations != undefined) return variations;
                    }
                    return [char];
                 });

    // up to this point splitLetters will be like this
    //  [["ا","إ","أ","آ"],["ي","ى","ي"],["ا"],["م"],["ن"],["ا"]]
    var res = [];
    recurse(splitLetters, 0, '', res); // this function will generate all the permuations
    return res;
}

function recurse(letters, index, cur, res){
    if(index == letters.length){
        res.push(cur);
    } else {
        for(var letter of letters[index]) {
            recurse(letters, index + 1, cur + letter, res );
        }
    }
}

var sameLetters = [     // represents the variations that you want to enumerate
    ['ا', 'إ', 'أ', 'آ'],
    ['ي', 'ى', 'ي']
];

var word = 'أيامنا';    
var customIndices = [0, 1]; // will make variations to the letters in these indices only. leave it empty for all indices

var ans = solve(word, sameLetters, customIndices);
console.log(ans);
```